# Azure AD B2C User Account Management from JavaScript Clients

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I used this **dotnetcore** sample [ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management) to get all the users from a **AD B2C** Directory.

Can this be achieved from a JavaScript client like **Angular** using some API? I'm trying not to use an **Azure Function** with the SDK code but directly call any existing Azure service from the Angular application itself to get the users.

**UPDATE:**

I used

```
    "@azure/@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-alpha.0",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.7.0"
```

and can login and logout from Azure AD B2C.

But the login requires username and password. I can't get all the users in the B2C with the token that I get after login. I get **authentication failed** error.

I think my app needs to access the B2C directory without login and password by following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service. This is for **Background services (daemons)** applications. Now I have to use two libraries to get tokens (one to login and one to get the users).

I'm confused by a few different libraries also:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/angular
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-javascript-sdk
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/use-toolkit-with-angular

1. Can I achieve the *login* as well as *reading the users* with a single library **@azure/msal-angular** and the same token?
2. Can I read the users only using **Background services (daemons)** flow only and not by **"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"**?

Comment: I think you can use the Graph API to get what you need. This might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the title **Azure AD B2C user account management with .NET Core and Microsoft Graph**, it calls Microsoft Graph API.

Microsoft Graph provides the [Javascript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-javascript-sdk).

You can refer to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#response) to list the Azure AD B2C users.

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

let res = await client.api('/users')
    .get();
```

An [Angular sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular) for your reference.

Comment: I added some more information in the **UPDATE** section of the original question. My question is now can I use **"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"** to both login using the login popup as well as read the users in the B2C. I'm trying to avoid the **daemon** flow.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the same app (website) to “read users” via graph and login via an AAD B2C user flow. *These are not the same tokens, they are acquired from different token issuers -AAD/AAD B2C*. MSAL supports both token endpoints. What you’re asking to do doesn’t make much sense. A user read op is usually server side (AAD token endpoint/Graph API/client_credential). A user login is client side (AAD B2C authorise endpoint/Your API/Auth Code). This means a user who logs in via AAD B2C cannot call Graph API. Read for more info - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56756#issuecomment-652903203
2. Sure, just follow an *Azure AD* guide for Graph API access. Yes it works in AAD B2C directories.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node

Comment: Is the ONLY way to 'read users' via graph API by using **appid client credentials** only and not via using **user name and password**?

Comment: Am I right in making a conclusion that a B2C user with **Global Administrator** permission won't be able to read the users in the same B2C or update those users?

Comment: No, that is not correct, this is all covered under AAD concepts, being AAD B2C makes no difference. You just must create an AAD App reg (type: “accounts in this org only”) in this directory, and assign delegated permissions to it for Graph API, then use AAD ROPC flow to get your tokens server side. (PS what you assume in your comments would mean you couldn’t even use the Azure Portal to administrate users! It’s the same concept)

Comment: My current setting is a **default directory** and a new **B2C** directory called **mycolleagues**. I can administer all the B2C users in **mycolleagues** in the Azure Portal. All the users can login and logout through my angular application. I can also administer the users using SDK and app credentials. What I really want is a user in the *B2C* be able to login, read all the users and change any data from my angular app without using the SDK on the server side but by using the GraphAPI from the client.

Comment: I tried creating a **AAD user** in the B2C directory (not a B2C user). I set the GlobalAdministrator role also. I got the Token using the login and password. I tried to read the users using that token. But I get the error that the user does not have permission to read users. I used the [postman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman) **On Behalf Of a User** APIs.

Comment: But I get the users if I use the second collection called **Application**. That made me to believe that I can read the users only by using the **application** credentials.